# How can I change a function in a parent theme via a child themes functions.php

Tags: functions, child-theme, parent-theme

I have a function in a parent theme:

```
function cyberchimps_logo_icons() { ?>
<header id="cc-header" class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span7">
        <?php if (function_exists('cyberchimps_header_logo') ) {
            cyberchimps_header_logo();
        } ?>
    </div>  

    <div id="register" class="span5">
        <?php if (function_exists('cyberchimps_header_social_icons') ) {
            cyberchimps_header_social_icons();
        } ?>
    </div>
</header>
<?php }
add_action('cyberchimps_header_content', 'cyberchimps_logo_icons');
```

I want to remove the social icons by removing the second half of this function. What's the best way to ADD something to a child themes functions.php to over ride this? I tried copying and pasting this into the child themes functions.php file, and deleting what I wanted gone, but the same function name can't be called twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the init action, remove the action calling their function and enqueue an action calling your (differently named) function, like this:

```
add_action('init', 'wpse_80107_init');

function wpse_80107_init() {
    // remove parent theme's header content action
    remove_action('cyberchimps_header_content', 'cyberchimps_logo_icons');

    // add child theme's header content action
    add_action('cyberchimps_header_content', 'wpse_80107_logo_icons');

}

function wpse_80107_logo_icons() {
    // your custom code here
}
```

Comment: what does the last argument in add_filter do? that '20'?

Comment: a) it's the [priority](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action#Parameters), i.e. when in the list of init actions to fire; b) it's just some copypasta from other code, I'll remove it from my answer as it's probably not needed here :)

Comment: Also, that should really be add_action, not add_filter! Bad copypasta, no doughnut!